EXIF.getData() function always returns an empty string and "undefined"
I'm developing a simple Chromium extension that reads EXIF data and shows to the user but in the library I'm using (which is Exif.js), I feel like there are things I'm not doing correctly because the output is always an empty string and undefined. Here's the code:
const img = document.getElementById("someImage");

window.onload = getExif(img);

function getExif(file) {
    try {
        EXIF.getData(file, function () {
            if (file) {
                var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
                var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
                var allMetaData = EXIF.pretty(this);

                console.log(JSON.stringify(allMetaData, null, 2));
                console.log(make, model);
            } else {
                console.error("EXIF data has not been found or incomplete.");
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error reading EXIF data", error);
    }
}

"make" and "model" always returns an "undefined" from an image I'm using through classical const img = document.getElementById(someImage) in popup.html as well as allMetaData returning and empty string.
I've followed the "Usage" section in the documentation but nothing appears to be fixing this.

Replace window.onload = ... with window.onload = () => getExif(document.getElementById("someImage"))

@gokacinlar; This works on my end, you can try to run the code snippet;


<html lang="en">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/exif-js/exif-js/master/example/DSCN0614_small.jpg" id="img1" />
<div id="exifData">Make : <span id="imgMake"></span> Model : <span id="imgModel"></span></div>
 
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/exif-js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=getExif;

    function getExif() {
        var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
        EXIF.getData(img1, function() {
            var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
            var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
            document.getElementById("imgMake").innerHTML = make;
            document.getElementById("imgModel").innerHTML= model;
        });
    }
</script>
</html>




Hi. I was able to solve the issue which was caused by images I'm using not having any exif data available to be displayed as output. After taking a picture of my cat with my phone and testing with it, it's finally working. Code has no problems...
